# Is it written literally in the bible that Miriam and Aaron were older siblings of Moses?

Tags: moses

I have always been told that Miriam and Aaron were **older** siblings of Moses.
I've seen the same thing on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miriam):

> Miriam (Hebrew: מִרְיָם‎ Mīrəyām) was described in the Hebrew Bible as
> the daughter of Amram and Jochebed, and the older sister of Moses and
> Aaron. She was a prophetess and first appears in the Book of Exodus.

Is it written literally in the bible, or it's a tradition only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it written literally in the bible that Miriam and Aaron were older siblings of Moses?

Yes, Miriam and Aaron are brother and sister to Moses:

> And the name of Amʹram’s wife was Jochʹe·bed, Leʹvi’s daughter, whom his wife bore to Leʹvi in Egypt. And to Amʹram she bore Aaron and Moses and their sister Mirʹi·am.  ([Nu 26:59](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200003074/0/0))

> <sup>**1**</sup> The sons of Leʹvi were Gerʹshon, Koʹhath, and Me·rarʹi. <sup>**2**</sup> The sons of Koʹhath were Amʹram, Izʹhar, Hebʹron, and Uzʹzi·el. <sup>**3**</sup> The children of Amʹram were Aaron, Moses, and also Mirʹi·am. And the sons of Aaron were Naʹdab, A·biʹhu, El·e·aʹzar, and Ithʹa·mar. ([1Ch 6:1-3](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200003074/0/1))

Miriam is older than Moses:

> <sup>**1**</sup> About that time, a certain man of the house of Leʹvi married a daughter of Leʹvi. <sup>**2**</sup> And the woman became pregnant and gave birth to a son. When she saw how beautiful he was, she kept him concealed for three months. <sup>**3**</sup> When she was no longer able to conceal him, she took a papyrus basket and coated it with bitumen and pitch and put the child in it and placed it among the reeds by the bank of the Nile River. <sup>**4**</sup> But **his sister stood at a distance to see what would happen to him.** ([Ex 2:1-4](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200000005/1/0)) [bold mine]

And Aaron is older than Moses:

> Moses was 80 years old and Aaron was 83 years old when they spoke to Pharʹaoh. ([Ex 7:7](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200000005/1/1))

[All scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]